Our Community Promotion Ads
One way we can promote this site is to create a community promotion ad to be shown on other SE sites. Each graduated SE site has a meta question where people can submit these ads (math, physics), and if they receive enough upvotes (>6) they will be automatically shown by the system.
If we are going to be advertising RE this way, I think it would be useful to have one designated ad to represent the site, and then submit it to the community promotion ad questions on all related sites. So I'm posting this meta question to collect ideas. After a few days we can take the top voted submission and "distribute" it. 
When an actual community ad is submitted, it is required to be in the form
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

   [1]: http://image-url
   [2]: http://clickthrough-url 

The image must be exactly 220x250 pixels, in GIF or PNG format (not animated), and hosted on SE's Imgur account. I don't think it's strictly necessary for answers to this question to follow that format, but it would be convenient. Answers posted here should definitely include the three required elements:

Image
Tagline
URL.


Target Sites :

Math : 2013 Thread
Electronics : 2013 Thread
IT Security : 2013 Thread
Theoretical CS : 2013 Thread

Other possible sites :

https://photo.stackexchange.com/
https://diy.stackexchange.com/
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
https://serverfault.com/
https://superuser.com/ 


I suggest that whichever post gets >=6 votes, and is the maximum voted post, be used.
And we have a winner!
Does that mean this thread is over? Of course, not! 
The more ideas we have, the more ads we can put across the network. So, dont hesitate to post.  

Post taken from Mathematica Meta

I may be the only one to wonder, but why is StackOverflow missing from the list?

@0xC0000022L [so] and MSO have Open Source Advertising in the sidebars and not the Community Promotion Ads that all other graduated sites have.

aah, I see. Then, of course, it makes sense.

@CamilStaps Its a matter of identity and a matter of getting 6 votes per ad on every site. There are no SE restrictions but rather the limiting factor is how much support it gathers.

Alright, although I am far from a creative (in the graphics designer sense), I gave it a shot.
More than anything we need to advertise out community so I came up with three entries. As I mentioned before, I am not a designer, so don't bludgeon me to death.
Please feel free to pick up an idea and "steal" the slogan or aspects of the graphics.
WARNING: I advise you to wear sunglasses for your eyes' protection before scrolling down ;)
3
Punch line: "What's going on? Help us find out!"

[![What's going on? Help us find out!][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/fgO5D.png
  [2]: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/


Posted on :
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9783/34912
https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2940/18583
https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1282/24389
https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2685/9954

Give it a shot yourself
You can find the source files over at: https://bitbucket.org/0xC0000022L/re.se-community-ad

I love this one! Could you just tweak the background to be a little lighter or maybe blue-er ?

@AshRj: I need to actually store the projects first (oops). Hadn't thought of someone requesting tweaks. I'll create an account on Bitbucket and upload it there. Was using Paint.NET.

Or alternatively, try to make the text brighter/darker. I say this because the green is blending with the grey, making the text a little hard to read. Specifically, the regions just over the greys. I am also not a graphics designer, so not sure what would be the best way to tackle that.

@AshRj: modified the version, put up the files in a repository on Bitbucket.

Looks real good now!

Time for RE to show up everywhere. Once you start posting the ads, add the links to the answers back in this answer for easy reference. If you need any help covering all the sites, ping and I'll help you out.

I am very bad at making pictures, but what about a picture of a magnifying glass on a bunch of hexadecimal codes. And, through the magnifying glass we can see the original code (C code) ? Something like this (but better shaped):


Do you think users will concentrate and read the advert to decipher what the advert means ? Or alternatively, have you payed attention to the adverts that come up on SO in the sidebar ? Interesting idea, though :)

No, it was just a graphical way to try to represent reverse-engineering. But, my picture is just not good enough...

I agree, maybe I can shade away the background on the top of the image. But, I did this picture more to illustrate the concept than to propose it as a candidate... (I need more time to do something nice)

@perror: I think the magnifying glass should rather show assembly. But very nice idea. I had a similar one but didn't know how to implement.

The second one is much better :) However, sticking with the format either remove the first one from this answer or post another answer with the second one.

You are right, I did not think about the voting. I do it now.

I am very bad at making pictures, but what about a picture of a magnifying glass on a bunch of lines of code. And, through the magnifying glass we can see the hexadecimal code ? Something like this (but better shaped):


Alright, although I am far from a creative (in the graphics designer sense), I gave it a shot.
More than anything we need to advertise out community so I came up with three entries. As I mentioned before, I am not a designer, so don't bludgeon me to death.
Please feel free to pick up an idea and "steal" the slogan or aspects of the graphics.
WARNING: I advise you to wear sunglasses for your eyes' protection before scrolling down ;)
2
Punch line: "We're stuck in reverse - help us out!"

[![We're stuck in reverse - help us out!][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/FghYp.png
  [2]: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/


Alright, although I am far from a creative (in the graphics designer sense), I gave it a shot.
More than anything we need to advertise out community so I came up with three entries. As I mentioned before, I am not a designer, so don't bludgeon me to death.
Please feel free to pick up an idea and "steal" the slogan or aspects of the graphics.
WARNING: I advise you to wear sunglasses for your eyes' protection before scrolling down ;)
1
Punch line: "Find out what makes software tick"

[![Find out what makes software tick][1]][2]

  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/B8q5y.png
  [2]: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

